# Can't get two variables to concatenate

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-concatenation

I'm a newbie, making a little exercise to practice with arrays. I've tried solving this from previous articles but none seem to have the relevant scenario.

I want to randomly generate sentences into paragraphs using phrases from an array. I got the random sentence generation part working fine.

```
    var ipsumText = ["adventure", "endless youth", "dust", "iconic landmark", "spontaneous", "carefree", "selvedge","on the road", "open road", "stay true", "free spirit", "urban", "live on the edge", "the true wanderer", "vintage motorcyle", "american lifestyle", "epic landscape", "low slung denim", "naturaL"];

//a simple function to print a sentence //

var sentence = function (y) { 
var printSentence = "";
for (i=0; i<7; i++) { 
    //random selection of string from array //
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    printSentence += y [x] + " "; 
}
return printSentence
};

console.log(sentence(ipsumText));
```

But now I want to be able to add a comma or full stop to the end of the sentence.

Because each word/phrase from the array used in the sentence prints with a space after it, I need to add an extra word with a full stop or comma right after it to avoid the space between them. To do this I created an extra variable

```
 // create a word and full stop to end a sentence//
var addFullstop = ipsumText[Math.floor(Math.random() * ipsumText.length)] + ". ";
var addComma = ipsumText[Math.floor(Math.random() * ipsumText.length)] + ", ";
```

These variables work on their own how I expect. They print a random word with a comma or full stop right after them.

However now I can't work out how to get them to add to the end of the sentence. I have tried quite a few versions referencing articles here, but I'm missing something, because when I test it, I get nothing printing to the console log.

This is what I have most recently tried.

```
// add the sentence and new ending together //
var fullSentence = sentence(ipsumText) + addFullstop;
console.log(fullSentence)
```

Can someone explain why this wouldn't work? And suggest a solution to try? 
thanks

Comment: I copied the code into the snipplet and ran fine.

Comment: Your code works.  You may want to make your `addFullstop` a function though, so that it will generate a different word each time.  Right now it's assigned to a variable and doesn't change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mqaowcjd/ it works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ES6 fiddle:  http://www.es6fiddle.net/isadgquw/

Your example works.  But consider a different approach which is a bit more flexible.  You give it the array of words, how long you want the sentence to be, and if you want an ending to the sentence, pass in `end`, otherwise, just leave it out and it will not be used.

The first line generates an array of length `count` which is composed of random indices to be used to index into the words array.  The next line maps these indices to actual words.  The last line joins all of these into a sentence separated by a single space, with an optional end of the sentence which the caller specifies.

```
const randomSent = (words, count, end) =>
    [...Array(count)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length))
                     .map(i => words[i])
                     .join(' ') + (end || '')

randomSent (['one','two','x','compound word','etc'], 10, '! ')
// x x one x compound word one x etc two two!
```

To make it more flexible, consider making a function for each task.  The code is reusable, specific, and no mutable variables are used, making it easy to test, understand, and compose however you like:

```
const randInt = (lower, upper) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper-lower)) + lower

const randWord = (words) => words[randInt(0, words.length)]

const randSentence = (words, len, end) =>
    [...Array(len)].map(() => randWord(words))
                   .join(' ') + (end || '')

const randWordWithEnd = (end) => randWord(ipsumText) + end
const randWordWithFullStop = randWordWithEnd('. ')
const randWordWithComma    = randWordWithEnd(', ')

// Now, test it!
const fullSentWithEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, 8, '!!')
const fullSentNoEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, 5)
const fullSentComposed = fullSentNoEnd + randWordWithFullStop
```

Link again for convenience: http://www.es6fiddle.net/isadgquw/

Comment: Thanks for the time to respond with this.

Comment: I like the idea of the flexibility of the second fiddle. Is the first function here creating the length of the sentence, then the second one selecting the actual words to be used, same as the top fiddle? Can I just check, sorry if it's obvious - on the 5th line of code <[...Array(len) >  is the open [ and the ... part of the code or just shorthand? I've never seen that before. just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: @garrethwills `randInt` (I assume you mean this when you say "first function") gives you a random integer in the range `[lower, upper)`. `randWord` then selects a random word from `words` array you pass it, using the `randInt` function.   The `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and expands `Array(len)` inline.  The result are `len` number of `undefined` elements which are then used inside the array literal `[ ]` to give you an initial array to be able to `map` (essentially cheating to replace a `for` loop).

Comment: This helps a lot. Going to have another go with the above. Then will try to make the sentences into paragraphs.